# Get all taxes in the orders grid

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders, sales-order, order-grid

I have a list of taxes in Magento 1.9 and I need to display all this available taxes in the admin Order Grid. I found all this taxes in database in the **sales_order_tax**. Is there any way to display all this taxes?

My database table is look like this:

[image]

So the idea is: each tax must have their own column in the order grid

columns:

- HST-ON;
- HST-NS;
- GST;
- PST-BC;

I try something like this but is not work:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('sf' => $resource->getTableName('sales_order_tax')),
    'sf.entity_id=main_table.order_id',
    array(
        'sf.code'

    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file from path: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php to app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

Please use the below join,

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sf' => 'sales_order_tax'),'sf.order_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sf.amount'));
```

Add the tax column under _prepareColumns(),

```
 $this->addColumn('tax_amount', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax Amount'),
            'index' => 'amount',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));
```

Hope this will help you.

Thank you!

Comment: thank you so much and how I can put the column for rate code for example?

Comment: I use your code and I am to display only the amount, my question is how I can separate taxes?

Comment: Do you want to display each order tax amount in sales grid?

Comment: yes this is the idea

Comment: I need to display for example this column HST-ON and will contain amount only for HST-ON tax, the same for the next column HST-NS and so on

Comment: Please check my comment. It is updated now

Comment: this is what I do too, but not like this, because with something like will display all tax amounts, I need to be separated , I need to display for example this column HST-ON and will contain amount only for HST-ON tax, the same for the next column HST-NS and so on